# Conflict with js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict, qliksense

I'm creating a web mashup using qliksense where I'm using some js files and I noticed  that when I add the:

- tether.min.js
- smooth-scroll.min.js
- jquery.touchSwipe.min.js

I have a conflict

The other js file are :

- jquery.min.js
- popper.min.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- jquery.dropdown.min.js
- jarallax.min.js

I don't know if there is dependecies or even an order to respect.

Help would be great

Thank you

A.

Comment: In what way are you combining these files? How do you know there is a conflict? Do you get an error somewhere?

Comment: order matters, user popper after bootstrap, adn see in you console whats the conflict

Comment: @mac9416 : Actually I'm building a mashup within qliksense and how I saw there is a conflict is that when I comment these 3 lines script my qliksense object appears otherwise they are not displayed

Comment: @AhmedSunny thanks for the tips I will try this

Answer (score 1):

This is the order you need and there will be no conflict:

1- jquery.min.js (required for jquery parts of bootstrap and for jquery.dropdown.min.js)

2- popper.min.js (required for bootstrap dropdown. It has no dependency to nothing!)

3 or 4 or 5:  bootstrap.min.js **and** jquery.dropdown.min.js (only requires jquery) **and** jarallax.min.js (pure JavaScript with no dependency)

**Final note:**

if you suspect that there are multiple jquery included in each file, you can name you own jquery and use it like this:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var myJquery= jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

usage:

```
myJquery("#myelement")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try this tomorrow when I get back to work :)

Comment: Hello ! It's not working, because there is require.js file in a Qlik installation that actually contains jQuery. So it's overwritting my own jQuery file. I've now to find a way to not let this overwritting happen S.Ach

Comment: I have added an example to show how to use multiple jquery in one file. @S.Ach